# No Launcher activity found in android

Tags: android

This is beyond bothering me, I've looked at other peoples similar problems but I can't figure this one out! Please help me!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.benbreeceharley"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Instead of

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
```

Comment: Don't I just love these stupid mistakes. Thanks a lot saved me some time.

Comment: don't just vote up his answer if it helped.... mark it as the correct one... there is a tick next to his solution